# java log type of exception

Tags: java, logging, exception

Because of amount of Exceptions that may be thrown by a block of code, I am having to catch generic exception as follows:

```
...
try {
    //some scandalous code
    scandalousMethod();
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error(String.format("'%s'", e.class.getName())); //Need suggestions here
}
...
```

I need to log type of Exception caught in the catch block. I do not think that e.class.getName() will work. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to do `e.getClass()`, not `e.class`. `getClass()` is a method (defined on `Object`) that, at runtime, looks up the object's class.

Comment: e.getClass() worked. Thanks! If you post as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Have you considered actually looking at the documentation for Throwable and seeing which methods there sound like they'd do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do:

```
e.getClass()
```

instead of just `e.class`. The [`getClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) method is defined on `Object` (so it's available for all reference types) and looks up the object's type at runtime.

Incidentally, I don't know which logging framework you use, but most of them have overloads that take the exception as an argument. This is useful because the loggers can be set up to print the full stack trace, not just its method. It'd be something like:

```
log.error("my specific message", e);
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to log exceptions (in most of today's logging frameworks - JCL, log4j, Slf4j, logback) is to do something like the following:

> log.error("Error while processing scandalousMethod: Maybe some inputs here", e);

Note the ", e" at the end. This usually not only prints out the complete class name of the exception, but the message and the stacktrace as well.